# How to set alloy-ui scheduler event maximum timeout

Tags: liferay, liferay-aui, alloy-ui

I am using `alloy-ui` `scheduler`, I want when the event input popup is appeared it show default time slot max 30 minutes `( like: 12:00 to 12:30, 12:30 to 1:00)` but right now it is showing with 1 hour `( 12:00 to 1:00, 12:30 to 1:30)`.

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet of your scheduler config object and the event objects you are trying to add. The 1:00 hour is a default duration time (see https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.SchedulerEvent.html#attr_endDate). What did you use as endDate?

Comment: thanks, but i have done now by set the default duration by adding `duration:30`